# estimate for exterior harmonic function

Tags: harmonic-analysis, potential-theory, partial-differential-equations

**Problem** Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth, connected, bounded domain, consider Dirichlet boundary problem
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\Delta u=0, &\mathrm{in}\ \ \mathbb{R}^3-\overline{D} \\
&u=1, &\mathrm{on}\ \ \partial D \\
&u\rightarrow 0, & \mathrm{as} \ \ |x|\rightarrow \infty
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
Prove that $u\in L^6(\mathbb{R}^3-\overline{D})$.

**Attempt** Using layer potential technique, there exists $\phi\in L^2(\partial D)$ such that $u=S\phi$, where $S$ is single layer potential, i.e.
$$u(x)=-\int_{\partial D} \frac{\phi(y)}{4\pi |x-y|}\,dy \ \  \ \ x\in \mathbb{R}^3-\overline{D}$$
then by Green's identity
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3-\overline{D}} |\nabla u|^2 =\int_{\partial D} \partial_Nu\cdot u=\int_{\partial D} \partial_Nu=\int_{\partial D}\phi<\infty$$
the last equality use jump relation for single layer potential, so that $\nabla u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3-\overline{D})$. But I do not know how to estimate $u\in L^6(\mathbb{R}^3-\overline{D})$, any help will be appreciated.